# How to avoid empty factor levels in a plot?

Tags: r, plot, subset

Users,

I have this data frame:

```
A<- c(10,2,4,5,3,5,98,65,36,65,6,100,70,54,25,23,22,30,15,23)
B<- c(1,0.1,0.5,0.8,0.2,0.9,3,1.2,5.6,3.5,15.9,10.2,5,5.1,7.1,5,6,10,4,8)
C<- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d")
mydf<- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

and I did a subset keeping only the level "a".

```
subset<- subset(mydf, mydf$C=="a")
```

But when I make a plot (please see the image) the graph shows also the deleted levels.

```
plot(B~ C, data=subset)
```

How can I plot the subsetted data frame avoiding deleted levels?

[image: plot subset data]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `droplevels`:

```
subset$C <- droplevels(subset$C)
plot(B~ C, data=subset)
```

By the way, `subset` is not a good name for a data.frame.

Comment: I agree, I wanted to change the subset name but the answers came faster then my edit. Thank you Jilber

Answer (score 3):

```
str(subset)
#'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ A: num  10 2 4 5 3 5
# $ B: num  1 0.1 0.5 0.8 0.2 0.9
# $ C: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Remove the missing factor levels by means of `factor`:

```
subset$C <- factor(subset$C)

str(subset)
#'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ A: num  10 2 4 5 3 5
#$ B: num  1 0.1 0.5 0.8 0.2 0.9
#$ C: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: so easy! Thank you JT85

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
plot(B~ droplevels(C), data=subset)
```